# Saving file in TextEdit from command line on MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, odt

I have a batch (8k) of damaged .odt files. I discovered that opening and saving them in TextEdit fixed them. I would like to script that using node.js, but cannot find a way to save and close file from terminal. Is there a command to do that?

The final goal is to convert them to pdf, for which I am already using a script that runs LibreOffice in headless mode.

Comment: not sure about node.js, I would probably try to do this with AppleScript. As a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721393/applescript-open-file-with-textedit-and-export-them-as-pdf

Comment: @cello This was exactly what I needed, a good bit slower than I would have liked, but it worked without modifications for me. Thanks :)